# Inconsistent hover state for SVG circle when using different positions

Tags: svg, hover, positioning, geometry, absolute

First of all I'm new to front end coding so excuse the obvious (if the problem is that).

I have spent the past couple days trying to work with SVG circles and have had a horrible time doing so. The intention was to align 3 SVG circles (a small one in the center of the page and two large ones on each side). I FINALLY achieved this today, BUT the hover state behavior is now acting strange (I swear this never ends).

Here's the relevant code:

```
     <div id = "nodes">

     <!--         <object id = "about_nodes">
        <embed id = "left_about_svg" src = "resources/node-images/left-about-subnode.svg" type = "image/svg-iml"></embed>
        <embed id = "about_svg" src = "resources/node-images/about-node.svg" type = "image/svg-iml"></embed>
        <embed id = "right_about_svg" src = "resources/node-images/right-about-subnode.svg" type = "image/svg-iml"></embed>
     </object>-->

     <div id = "about_node">
         <object>
             <embed id = "about_svg" src = "resources/node-images/about-node.svg" type = "image/svg-iml"></embed>
         </object>
     </div>

     <div id = "left_about_subnode">
         <object>
             <embed id = "left_about_svg" src = "resources/node-images/left-about-subnode.svg" type = "image/svg-iml"></embed>
         </object>
     </div>

     <div id = right_about_subnode>
         <object>
             <embed id = "right_about_svg" src = "resources/node-images/right-about-subnode.svg" type = "image/svg-iml"></embed>
         </object>
     </div>
```

As you can see there's some commented out HTML. I was experimenting with different levels of containers to see if that was the problem. It wasn't.

The CSS:

```
#about_svg{
display: inline;
position: absolute;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: 2%;
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
border-radius: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#left_about_svg{
display: inline;
position: absolute;
width: 65%;
height: 65%;
left: 25%;
top: 3%;
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
border-radius: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#right_about_svg{
display: inline;
position: absolute;
width: 65%;
height: 65%;
left: 75%;
top: 3%;
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
border-radius: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

And the SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="about_node" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="-0.531 -0.583 25.063 25.114" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
 style="enable-background:new -0.531 -0.583 25.063 25.114;" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
    <style type="text/css">

    .circle{
        fill:white;
        stroke:#000000;
        stroke-miterlimit:10;}

    #about_node:hover .circle{
        fill: red;
        transition: 1s;
        stroke: red;
    }
    </style>
</defs>
<circle class = "circle" cx="12" cy="12" r="12"/>
```

At the moment all 3 circles have essentially the same SVG (**left and right circles don't have a hover state**) so I'll just post this one.

Basically, what I have figured out is that **absolute positioning** causes my embed object to have large rectangular box around it (observed when I used **inspect element**) around my circles (**about 3 diameters long**). The larger ones to the left and right of the small centered one are obscuring the hover state of the centered one.

The hover state works if I:

1) reduce the window by half mushing all of my circles together (another problem I need to fix), I'm able to just touch the tip of the small circle and change its color.

2) remove the two large circles to the left and right of the center one. However this places the hover state on the large rectangle of the embed object NOT the circle itself.

3) change everything to relative positioning everything gets messed up but the circle's hover state works properly and the embed object box becomes a square

**This seems to boil down to absolute positioning.** However, I cannot use relative because I lose scalability and it's impossible to position the elements (for me at least).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Christ I just want 3 circles in a line with hover capabilities! Why is this so hard!?

Comment: It's a bit hard to get a sense of what you are trying to achieve without a working example - or even a picture.  Your widths look strange. 65%+10%+65% > 100%. And why are you giving your SVGs a border radius?  Also, is there a reason your SVGs are external?

Comment: Sorry but aren't those height and width values a percentage of the container element? So 50% width would take up half of the container horizontally  and 50% height would take up 50% of the container vertically. I guess because it's a circle I only need one, but I don't think it has to sum to 100%.

And not all browsers support inline svg hence the external.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of thing you were after?

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/cUNZVqGQ8pa4ZrKy9Np5?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<object class="svg-left"
        type="image/svg+xml" data="circle.svg"></object>
<object class="svg-middle"
        type="image/svg+xml" data="circle.svg"></object>
<object class="svg-right"
        type="image/svg+xml" data="circle.svg"></object>
```

**CSS**

```
.svg-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
}

.svg-middle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}

.svg-right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 300px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

**SVG**

```
<svg version="1.1" id="about_node" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="-0.531 -0.583 25.063 25.114" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<defs>
    <style type="text/css">

    .circle{
        fill:white;
        stroke:#000000;
        stroke-miterlimit:10;}

    .circle:hover{
        fill: red;
        transition: 1s;
        stroke: red;
    }
    </style>
</defs>
<circle class = "circle" cx="12" cy="12" r="12"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry for not uploading a picture, but you got the right idea with this demo. You helped me discover an error too. The reason I had a border radius was because originally the hover state was responding to the viewbox of the about_node ("#about_node: hover .circle{...}"). The border-radius fixed this although I see it was unnecessary now. Also, I don't prefer to use pixels because it doesn't scale.

Comment: A better idea of how I want it:

https://plnkr.co/edit/8BfhejxyTPQRK3LFtFnn?p=preview

Notice however, that the more you compress the section the more out of wack the elements become. Maybe this is expected and I just am unaware, but how would I maintain scalability while not losing the inline layout of the circles?

Comment: Ignore that link. You DO need to specify both height and width if it's a circle: https://plnkr.co/edit/8BfhejxyTPQRK3LFtFnn?p=preview

Comment: You are limited by your insistence on absolutely positioning each circle.  You can't easily keep the SVGs in the same position relative to each other when each of them has a size and position tied to something else (the page).  If you need them to stay in the same position relative to one another, the simplest way is to put all the circles in the same SVG.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. It seems to make more sense to have them contained in a single SVG element and then center that object from there. I tried this before I posted the question actually and again just now but I just cannot achieve what I want. Perhaps I'm in over my head with SVGs at the moment. Moving back to regular CSS shapes for now.